# How to NOT connect to daemon?

Tags: start-up, emacs-daemon

When invoking emacs, is there a way to specify that it should *not* connect to any emacs daemon, but instead should run as an isolated instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I just earned dumbest question of the year with this question. The answer is simply to invoke `emacs`, as opposed to invoking `emacsclient`

Comment: +1 for the chuckle